# android bitmap to byte array without compression

Tags: android, android-studio, arrays, android-bitmap, image-compression

How can we convert bitmap image to byte array in Android without compressing the image? Image to byte array in Android:

```
 Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
 img_view.setImageBitmap(photo);
 Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo,512,512 , true);
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(photo.getWidth()*photo.getHeight());
 resizedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bos);
 bArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

Set image size between 300 to 400 kb.

Comment: What data format are you expecting the `byte[]` to be in? Your current code is using PNG, which uses lossless compression. What is your specific concern regarding compression?